# UWP Application - How to detect a CDRom or DVDRom device in StorageDevices

Tags: uwp, dvd, cd-rom, removable-storage

In a UWP application, I obtain all the removable devices with :

```
KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()
```

I want to exclude optical devices and keep only the external hard disk or flash devices.

I tried to find a suitable property by using the following :

```
device.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(...)
```

and tried a lot of properties from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/devices-bumper) but can't fin anything.

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could build an AQS filter string when you enumerate devices. See [Build a device selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/build-a-device-selector#building-the-filter-string).

If you are not familiar with the AQS format, you can read more at [Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax).

Comment: The problem I have is to find the right property to recognize optical devices.  An AQS filter also requires the right property, si it does not help.  What I need is a property, not a technology to search.